# Not able to define column type in JoinColumn for a foreign key reference in Symfony2/Doctrine

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

This seems like it should be an easy issue but I can't seem to get it solved.

I have two Entities, Person and Flag. Flag has a ManyToOne relationship to Person. Where I'm running into an issue is that Person's id field is a bigint, not a type int.

So, with syntax like this on the ManyToOne field on the Flag entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="flags")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="personId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $person;
```

I get a Foreign Key error, something along the lines of

```
An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE flags ADD CONSTRAINT FK_B0541BAA20C4B1C FOREIGN KEY
```

I believe I've exhausted all other possibilities of this error besides it being generated because the personId field is an integer and the person's ID field is a bigint. These foreign key relationships have been working fine among other entities in this bundle, its only the Person and its bigint primary key that is causing issues.

I can't add type="bigint" to JoinColumn without getting an error like:

```
The annotation @ORM\JoinColumn declared on property Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\PersonFlag::$person does not have a pro
  perty named "type"
```

And, if I add Column annotation in order to declare the type, it just ignores the JoinColumn, as shown below:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="flags")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="personId", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
 */
protected $person;
```

This doesn't generate any errors, but it creates a column named "person" that has no foreign keys.

So, what am I missing, how can I go about adding this ManyToOne relationship to an entity that has a bigint as it's primary key?

Here is the annotation for the Person entity's ID field:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="bigint")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

TY!

Comment: Can you post the "flags" property on Person model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In relationships between entities I think you could avoid the column type, because the foreign keys should be already mapped in the model (for example, the IDs). Try this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="flags")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="personId", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $person;
```

Then, in your person model you should have something like this:

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Flag", mappedBy="person")
 */
protected $flags;
```

Comment: I have tested with this code with `bigint` in person table as primary key. Works as expected.

Comment: Thank you Manix. I do believe my issue is something else now...I've been working on it all day and don't quite have it solidified yet but I may not finish today...I think my foreign key error was being caused by extra preexisting rows that didn't have a person entity.

Comment: Ohhh that has sence! hehe. However, I am glad to hear that everything goes fines :)