# How to add one-to-many FK that can be null

Tags: mysql

I am trying a basic relationship of ManyToOne between two entities A and B. The entity A already has been declared so the actual migration contains the creation of entity B and somehow the altering of A in order to accept the foreign key. I also had the problem showned in here: [Not able to define column type in JoinColumn for a foreign key reference in Symfony2/Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522404/not-able-to-define-column-type-in-joincolumn-for-a-foreign-key-reference-in-symf) (having the PK of A bigint, error with `cannot add foreign key`).

Fixed that and it's working only if I also delete the entity A and basically create them from scratch.
My code and migration with only the creation of B and altering A (that still causes error):
somehow I want the FK from A to also accept nullable values, I think the problem is in regard of that:

This was the first migration:

```
CREATE TABLE
 A(id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 value VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 datatype VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB
```

and now based of my code the following queries are being generated:

```
CREATE TABLE 
 B(id BIGINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
 name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 code INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 UNIQUE INDEX code_idx (code),
 PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE `utf8_unicode_ci` ENGINE = InnoDB
```

and:

```
ALTER TABLE
 A(table) ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D1DD32EBBF396750 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES B(table) (id)
```

But when I run the migrations no column has been put in the A table. I am really confused and not sure what to solve this. Has anyone had some clues?

EDIT:

My code in the entities is :

```
class A:

/**
 * @var B
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Model\B", inversedBy="aS")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $bId;

class B:
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned": true})
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Model\A", mappedBy="bid")
 */
private $aS;
```

Comment: Your `ALTER TABLE` is logically wrong. You try to refer one primary key to another. 1) Each primary key is unique, so you may obtain One-to-One, not One-to-Many. 2) The table  cannot refer to another table by autoincremented field.

Comment: Add a field into the table `A` structure and refer it to table `B`, like `ALTER TABLE A ADD COLUMN table_B_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, ADD CONSTRAINT FK_D1DD32EBBF396750 FOREIGN KEY (table_B_id) REFERENCES B (id)`.

Comment: I added an edit. Basically that's my code and the generated query was resulted by doctrine.

Comment: @Akina I've did what you suggested and it's working but I am not sure how to transform this in doctrine code in order to generate your query..

Comment: The only thing I know about doctrine is that it exists.

Comment: @Akina lol :))) thank you very much either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping is a little flawed(or you actually intended to do it like this)
**This is your code fixed**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="a")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ARepository")
 */
class A
{
    /**
     * @var B
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="B", inversedBy="aS")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $bId;
}
```

And this is the prefered solution

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="a")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ARepository")
 */
class A
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", options={"unsigned": true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="auto")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var B
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="B", inversedBy="aS")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $b;
}
```

In your A entity you actually map object B not its ID